# Is there any maximum nesting level for angularjs directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have next directives: `schema`, `record`, `field` and `type`.

In the view I am using `schema` directive which in template contains `record`.
Inside `record` template there is usage of `field` directive and inside `field` directive there is usage of `type` directive. (nesting level = 4)

- schema

  - record

    - field

      - type

Field directive code:

```
.directive("field", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
                replace: true,
                transclude: true,
                scope: {
                    field: '='
                },
                template: "<tr><td>{{field.name}}</td><type type='field.type'></type><td>{{field.type}}</td></tr>"
    }
  })
```

Type directive code:

```
.directive("type", function($compile){
    return{
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            type: '='
        },
        template: "<td>test</td>"
    }
  })
```

Part of output from rendering `field` and `type` directives:
`size   ["null","long"]` (no results from `type` directive evaluation).

What is interesting, is that when I put `type` directive one level higher(inside template of `record`) everything renders properly:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems was related to the definition of template of `field` directive.
Inside `<tr>` tag you cannot put something that is not surrounded but `<td>` even if this is directive that will generate proper surrounding (`<td>...</td>`).

Updating directive to next states:

field:

```
.directive("field", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
                replace: true,
                transclude: true,
                scope: {
                    field: '='
                },
                template: "<tr><td>{{field.name}}</td><td><type type='field.type'></type></td><td>{{field.type}}</td></tr>"
    }
  })
```

type:

```
 .directive("type", function($compile){
        return{
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                type: '='
            },
            template: "test"

        }
      })
```

solves problem.